# Build runner error Could not start worker thread: result = 22

Tags: flutter, build-runner

[image: I am attaching the error screenshot error.]

The problem is it showing 315: error: Could not start worker thread: result = 22.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the answer, the problem was lying on the file name.
Firstly the file name was like Mobile%20Team%20Test%20Project and I changed it to MobileTeamTestProject.

So, try to change the app name to normal name instead of special character or spaces.

Answer (score 2):

You must use a-z characters, also numbers in
file name will cause the same error

Answer (score 1):

You must use a-z characters,

> Numbers and special characters are not allowed in the file name

unless you will get the same error

Answer (score 1):

Yes, try to change the app name to normal alphabets.